# Error when running Flyway on JBoss 7

Tags: java, jboss, flyway

I'm trying to set up my application so it will automatically upgrade the database when it's deployed in any envrionment so I have added the following to the Spring config:

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
<property name="url"    value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${db.host}:${db.port}:${db.database}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="4" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="5000" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    <property name="defaultReadOnly" value="false" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select '1' from DUAL" />
</bean>
<!-- ADDED IN AN ATTEMPT TO FIX THE PROBLEM -->
<bean id="flyway-init" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" init-method="init">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="flyway" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate" depends-on="flyway-init">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
</bean>
```

but when I run it in JBoss 7 I get the following error:

`com.googlecode.flyway.core.validation.ValidationException: Found non-empty schema 'WMYERS' without metadata table! Use init() first to initialize the metadata table.`

I have already run a flyway clean-migrate against the database so it is already set up and ready to go and the SCHEMA_HISTORY table is present, any ideas?

Comment: turns out the previous developer had specified a different name for the init table for some bizarre reason....once I removed this it all works great!

Answer (score 0):

Flyway default checks that non empty schema has been properly initialized. This check ensures Flyway doesn't migrate or clean wrong db in case of configuration mistake. Migration failed and this exception was thrown because metadata table with defined name should exist and be non empty when schema of your db has some data. Probably the metadata table was modified manually.